# Change javascript variable with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my MVC project i import a .js file in my shared layout.

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootbox.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This file has this variable

```
var locales = {
            en: {
                OK: "OK",
                CANCEL: "Nej",
                CONFIRM: "Ja"
            }}
```

In one of the views i would like to change the `OK` value for `en` with jQuery. How can i do this?

Comment: `locales.en.OK = 'en';`?

Comment: doesnt work, says its not defined

Comment: can we access js variable in one view to other?

Comment: Have you checked the scope of your JavaScript files? It sounds like the variable is out of scope where you're trying to access it.

Comment: @TobiasOlofsson Is the `var` defined within the body of a `function`? If it is, it won't be directly reachable from outside of that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the file defines locales as a global variable,

```
locales.en.OK = 'en';
```

To be clear, though, this has nothing to do with jQuery, razor, or model-view-controller. It's simply how you set the property of an object in native Javascript, there's no further technology required to do this.

---

I have now downloaded bootbox.js myself to look at what's going on here. locales is *not* defined as a global variable, it's scoped to the anonymous wrapper function that contains all of the contents of bootbox.js.

This means that there is no way to change the contents of that variable dynamically from outside of that scope. If you want to permanently change that text, then you can change it in bootbox.js manually. If you want to change it dynamically, then you can replace

```
var locales = ...
```

with

```
window.locales = ...
```

in bootbox.js, and then use my original suggestion in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You may declare `locales` in some scope, define `locales` outside of scope that is global or just remove `var` from `locales` as mentioned below.

```
locales = {
  en: {
    OK: "OK",
    CANCEL: "Nej",
    CONFIRM: "Ja"
}}
```

You can call it by `locales.en.OK`